# "if" statement for validating a form doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email

I have this newsletter form with email input generated with wordpress plugin. Form action is set to a sub-page. I want to check if given email adress is correct - if not, I want to print an alert message.

```
let emailField = document.querySelector('.email').value;
const regEx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');
let form = document.querySelectorAll('.newsletter-container > form');

function validateEmail() {
  if (regEx.test(emailField) == false) {
    alert('!!!');
    event.preventDefault();
   } else {
    form.submit();
   }
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   validateEmail();
});
```

My problem is, when I type a correct email adress I still get alert and button default event is prevented from action.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to grab the `emailField` value **inside** the function.

Comment: By the way, this behaviour comes out of the box in HTML5, `<input type="email" />`

Comment: @psilocybin - omg you're right, thanks and sorry for my dummy question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strange construct but anyhow

```
 let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');



 function validateEmail() {
   var regEx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    let emailField = document.querySelector('.email').value;
    if (regEx.test(emailField) == false) {
       alert('!!!');
        event.preventDefault();
   } else {
      let form = document.querySelectorAll('.newsletter-container > form');
      form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do you think it's strange? Yes- HTML5 comes with simillar solution, but it's not working with empty input in my case so I need something custom.

Comment: Old school we woud have The form Name and Input name, use the submit event to call the JS function and  we was done. There was and is no need for a query selector. :) It just makes it more confusing unreadable and i guess also slower. Ok doesnt matters in this case. document.forms[form.name][fieldname].value would for example get your inut field as well. Very old school and very simple. OK your html should be have also valid names for forms and input fields :) Thats why i say its strange.